# open google map on html->link click cakephp through javascript

Tags: cakephp, google-maps-api-3

i am trying to implement google map with cakephp. I wish to open google map on `html->link` click in my view. Following is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("../images/route.png", array("alt" => "altText")),
                     array('controller' => 'ctrllerName', 'action' => 'actionName'),
                    array('escape' => false)); ?>
```

function i need to call on link click:

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAgrj58PbXr2YriiRDqbnL1RSqrCjdkglBijPNIIYrqkVvD1R4QxRl47Yh2D_0C1l5KXQJGrbkSDvXFA"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

 function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        var center = new GLatLng(21.19500,  72.81944);
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});  
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
       var point = marker.getPoint();
          map.panTo(point);
       document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);

        });


     GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
          map.clearOverlays();
    var center = map.getCenter();
          var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(5);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(5);


     GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
      var point =marker.getPoint();
         map.panTo(point);
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(5);
         document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(5);

        });

        });

      }
    }
</script>
```

how do i call this function on link click in cakephp so that it displays the google map?

Comment: [Version 2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) of the Maps API is deprecated, and is warranted only until 19 May 2013 . You should use [Version 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for new developments

Comment: ok sure but that does not answers my question

Comment: why don't you call load function on that link click event.?

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: you can make function in your controller and then give the controller and action of that function, it's easy to do link to open your google map. hope u understand

Comment: `$this->Html->link('loadmap', 'javascript:load()');`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate 'a href="javascript:void(0)"' like link in cakephp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278278/how-to-generate-a-href-javascriptvoid0-like-link-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your goal is to call the load() method when the user clicks on the link, the code would be the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image(../images/route.php),
     array('controller' =>'ctrllerName', 'action' => 'actionName'),
     array('escape' => false, 'onclick' => 'load()')
); ?>
```

However, I'm going to assume that if you want to call a piece of JavaScript on the page you probably don't want to go to a different page, in which case you can change the code to the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
     $this->Html->image(../images/route.php),
     '#',
     array('escape' => false, 'onclick' => 'load()')
); ?>
```